# Form needs to post data to a controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have a form,

```
<form>
<input id="amount"  type="text" placeholder="Give amount"  name="myamount"/>
<button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="btn1" >FirstBTN</button> 
<button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="btn2">SecondBTN</button>
</form>
```

Which needs to post data to a function inside the controller. I am trying to make two buttons, post data to two different controller functions. And this is my jquery code written in html file (view):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn1').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'helloworld/firstmoney',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'submit' : true ,myamount: $("#amount").val()},
            success: function (result) {

            }
        });  
 });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btn2').click(function() { 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'helloworld/secondmoney',
                type: 'POST',
               data: {'submit' : true ,myamount: $("#amount").val()},
                success: function (result) {

                }
            });  

    });

    </script>
```

Here is the controller but I am not getting any values in my controller..

```
public function firstmoney(){
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $Money = $this->input->post("myamount");
        $data =  array(
        'Money' => $Money
         );
        $this->load->view("page1", $data);

    }

public function secondmoney(){
            $this->load->helper('form');

            $Money = $this->input->post("myamount");
            $data =  array(
            'Money' => $Money
             );
            $this->load->view("page2", $data);

        }
```

my controller name is helloworld and I need to assign values in $money but I cant get it working. I am a beginner programmer so please do tell me what steps I should follow.

Comment: It does not appear that you are sending any of the form data to your backend page.

Comment: @Draco18s I was checking out ways to use jquery and ajax so this is the thing I found, I wasnt sure if this was right, so posted here for help

Comment: You can absolutely use AJAX for this, but you have to send the data (see that `data{ submit:true }` chunk?  That's the data you're sending).

Comment: @Draco18s so how can I send the data from the input field there ?

Comment: `data {'submit':true,'money':$('#amount').val()}`

Comment: @Draco18s what does 'money' do ? or should it be 'Money' ? 
I wrote it like this.. 
$('#btn1').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'helloworld/firstmoney',
            type: 'POST',
           data {'submit':true,'money':$('#amount').val()} 
        });  

});

Comment: Ah, yes, it should be `'Money'` I made a mistake there.  It is that string because that's the value your PHP script is looking for: `'Money' => $Money`

Comment: @Draco18s also there is one problem, in my controller it says post(myamount) so doesnt it mean that the submit place it should have myamount instead of 'Money'

Comment: Uh.... you may be right.  I had all of like 3 weeks using PHP.  I could tell on the JS side what was wrong, but I was guessing on the PHP.

Comment: In your JS, you're sending the data with a key of `mymoney` whereas in your controller, you're looking for a key of `myamount` -- if you adjust your code so both of those values are the same, then it should pull in the correct values.

Comment: @sbeliv01 yea I meant my amount, but even after I fixed that its not working.

Answer (score 0):

First, your AJAX should look like this one.

```
    $('#btn2').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'helloworld/secondmoney',
            method: 'POST',//not type
            data: { myamount: $("#amount").val() }//no need for submit variable (although you can use it) since this will be submitted on click; no quotes over variables
        })
          .done(function(result)) {
              //do your stuff on response
          });
    });
```

Second: no need for ajax and you should use classic form with post method because you are making redirection in controller/method where data is posted to.
AJAX requires JSON formated response, and it is not in this case. So wether change view to have form with method and action, wether change controller/method to return JSON string back to AJAX.

Comment: What does it say in Developers Tools?

Comment: I am using netbeans and trying to debug the controller, but since it doesnt reach the controller I cannot debug it, and console doesnt say anything..

Comment: What status code you have got? Are you being redirected to other page? You have to return JSON string to make AJAX work as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I dont get directed to any page, I am in the same page, what do you mean by return JSON string, where can I do that ?

Comment: `result` variable in AJAX has to be string or JSON encoded array that is echoed back. You shouldn't load new view, but echo one of these. You should have status code 200 in Network tab when action is finished.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var base_url= '<?php echo base_url() ?>';


 url: base_url+'helloworld /firstmoney',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try another way to do that

Try below code

form

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
<input id="amount"  type="text" placeholder="Give amount"  name="myamount"/>
<button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="btn1" >FirstBTN</button> 
<button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="btn2">SecondBTN</button>
</form>
```

Then you can add jquery to change the form action on submit button clicks
like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#btn1').click(function() { 
        $('#myform').attr('action', 'Your domain/Your controller/firstmoney'); 
 });

$('#btn2').click(function() { 
        $('#myform').attr('action', 'Your domain/Your controller/secondmoney'); 
 });

</script>
```

Now your form will call firstmoney() if you click #btn1 and it will call secondmoney() if you call #btn2

And you can get form data using

```
$this->input->post('myamount');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print $_POST data then apply this code for btn1.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn1').click(function() { 
    event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({ 

            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "helloworld/firstmoney",         
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'submit' : true ,myamount: $("#amount").val()},
            success: function (result) { 
                $("body").html(result);
            }
        });  
    });
});
```

In your helloworld controller

```
public function firstmoney(){

    $Money = $this->input->post("myamount");
    $data =  array(
    'Money' => $Money
     );
    $data = $this->load->view("page1", $data, TRUE); //it will return that page and save it in $data 
}
```

In you page1.php view write the following code

```
<?php
echo $Money;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn1').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'helloworld/firstmoney',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'submit' : true ,myamount: $("#myamount").val()},
            success: function (result) {

            }
        });  
 });
```

Keep the id and name value as myamount in above input tag and change in the jquery code also